# Scheduling Dataflow pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to schedule a google dataflow job to run every one hour

I check this url https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions
but I got many errors.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, using app engine is trying to repurpose a good tool for something different.

We opted to run our own CRON instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check doing such case using google dataflow windowing with unbounded source
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/gaming-example

Answer (score 0):

You can Use a Cloud scheduler that runs every 1 hour and calls a cloud function,
The Cloud function will use the Dataflow client API library to submit a Dataflow job.

Check this link https://dzone.com/articles/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions